# Is Promise a technique to realize asynchronous programming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I've tried to understand [Promise](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3.29.45/src/promise.js?autodive=0/)
from google source, and haven't found how it execute code asynchronously.

My understanding of asynchronous function is that code below it can be resolved at a time before it.

For example:

```
setTimeout(()=>{console.log("in")}, 5000);
console.log("out");

// output:
// out
// in
```

The second line fufilled before the first line , so I think `setTimeout` is an asynchronous tech. But see this code of `Promise`:

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{console.log('in'); resolve(1);});
console.log("out");

//in
//out
```

This code block is actually excuted line by line, if `console.log('in');` is a time-consuming operation, the second line will be blocked until it's resolved.

We usually use `Promise` like this:

```
(new Promise(function1)).then(function2).then(function3)
```

Does this mean: `Promise` is just used to promise that function2 is executed after function1, it's not a tech to realize `asynchronous` ，but a method to realize `synchronous` (function1, function2, function3 are executed sequently).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise is just a way to describe a value that does not exist yet, but will arrive later. You can attach `.then` handlers to it, to get notified if that happens.

> Does this mean: Promise is just used to promise that function2 is executed after function1?

Yes exactly, even if function1 returns it's value asynchronously (through a Promise), function2 will run only if that value is present.

> it's not a tech to realize 'asynchronous' but a method to realize 'synchronous' [execution] ?

Not really. It makes little sense to wrap a value that already exists into a promise. It makes sense to wrap a callback that will call back "asynchronously" into a promise. That said, the Promise itself does not indicate wether the value it resolves to was retrieved in a synchronous or asynchronous maner.

```js
function retrieveStuffAsynchronously() {
   // direclty returns a Promise, which will then resolve with the retrieved value somewhen:
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // directly executes this, the async action gets started below:
      setTimeout(() => { // the first async code, this gets executed somewhen
         resolve("the value"); // resolves asynchronously
      }, 1000);
   });
}

console.log(retrieveStuffAsynchronously()); // does return a promise immeadiately, however that promise is still pending
retrieveStuffAsynchronously().then(console.log);
```

---

Sidenote: However, Promises are guaranteed to resolve asynchronously:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  console.log('one'); 
  resolve('three');
});

promise.then(console.log); // guaranteed to be called asynchronously (not now)

console.log("two");
```